# Ranger File Manager error

Tags: bash

When I run the ranger file manager in X11 on my mac, the message "no manual entry for ranger" keeps popping up after I hit any of the arrow keys. Anyone has had the same problem and knows how to resolve it?

Comment: Something seems to be calling `man ranger` which is typically what displays this error, try `man` for a builtin or a non existing executable and you'll see the same error. Can you confirm a manual isn't installed by running `man ranger`?

Comment: I did "man ranger" and got "no manual entry for ranger", so I guess no manual is installed. I also found that it is only when I hit the "down" arrow the error shows.

Comment: This is no problem really, you are just missing the manual. The program shouldn't even want to show it but anyway. Try to reinstall it or just ignore it, seems like the mac version is just buggy.

Comment: yeah I reinstalled it and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot!